# How to find the direction of north, south, east and west on a map bing?

Tags: geolocation, geometry, bing, bing-maps

I started a few days ago to work ave bing map.
I want to get a picture and be able to determine the direction or is the following values:
**North, South, East, West** ...
However I do not see how to calculate ... I'm pretty sure my question is too easy for most people. Hopefully I pissed anyone with my stupid question ^ ^

Here is a picture of my problem. I know the original position in the middle.

Anyone know there a **practical formula to determine the direction of** north, south, east and west?
Or Is it possible to ask to **generate the map by moving north up the default** ?
I use Bing maps Soap Service

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: I do not know .. this is possible and I would seem logique.If anyone can confirm this ? I close immediately this useless post

Comment: I confirm that the image is always generated using North as top element while using the Static Imagery API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using the Bing Maps REST Imagery service, the heading of the image is always North = top of the image.

See, there are no parameter that allows you to change the heading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Comment: ohh ok. I use Bing Soap ImageryService. But i think it's the same ?

Comment: Yes, same one even if I highly recommend to use the REST service since there are more options.